# Can't serve up files with custom file extension in ASP.NET despite mimetype declaration?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, mime-types

I'm working on an ASP.NET/MVC/Razor web site.  I need to server up files with a "pdb" extension.  The *.pdb files are plain ASCII text files.  I tried adding the following declaration to my *web.config* file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".pdb" mimeType="text/plain" />
    </staticContent>    
</system.webServer>
```

But I still get a **404 error** whenever I try to load one of the files:

*HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.*

I found this SO post that talks about running a utility to register the version of .NET you are using, but I believe the context is that of installing a web site on to other serves, not just a simple publish scenario like mine:

["The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration." error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388066/the-page-you-are-requesting-cannot-be-served-because-of-the-extension-configura)

What am I doing wrong?  Note this is happening when I run locally with IIS Express from Visual Studio 2013 Update 4.

Comment: change the mimeType to application/octet-stream and see if the results change.  Also, ensure that your app is actually recycling (maybe even stop/start IIS express).  Lastly, .pdb is also the file extension for .NET debug symbol files, so there may be some security considerations coming into play with that particular extension.

Comment: @Tommy Thanks.  I'll try those tips now.  Which Web.config should I be modifying?  The one in the Views folder or the top level one?

Comment: @Tommy My problem was simpler sadly.  I was putting my Mime type declarations in the Views Web.config instead of the Global Web.config.  As soon as I moved the exact declaration I showed above into the Global Web.config, it started working.  Sorry for the confusion.  Quite frankly,  I don't even know what the purpose of the Views Web.config is.