# What is the worker process account in machine.config if <processmodel autoConfig="true">?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, iis-7, processmodel

I'm trying to run a website on localhost using IIS in Windows 10.
I'd like to be able to access the website through another pc in the lan using a local ip address and port. I just started debugging the application in visual studio 2015, I could run

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:51258:localhost" />
```

but using

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:51258:192.168.1.213" />
```

causes an "Access Denied" popup in visual studio

I've followed the steps in 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/kb/894433
but was confused with step 7 i.e.
*7. Add the worker process account that is configured in the processModel element in the Machine.config file*
I was able to locate the machine.config file but the process model is set to autoconfig=true i.e.

Do I have to setup a custom account or is there a default worker process account that I'm not seeing?

This is so that I can do the following steps to solve the access denied problem...
5. In the Policy pane, right-click Impersonate a client after authentication, and then click Properties.
6. Click Add User or Group.
7. Add the worker process account that is configured in the processModel element in the Machine.config file.

Please note that I have already added the IUSR with permissions to the directories I'm running the website from.

Answer (score 0):

ok after some more digging I finally made it work. I didn't have to add any worker account in the process model block of the *applicationhost.config*

I just had to install HTTP Activation from the advanced service as described in one of the answers in 
[what to do when accessing http://192.168.1.213:51258/Default.aspx doesnt work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388066/the-page-you-are-requesting-cannot-be-served-because-of-the-extension-configura)

I then followed with 
*netsh http add urlacl url=http://192.168.1.213:51258/ user=everyone*

But that didn't solve it so I followed the change of configuration in visual studio web server to use custom server to finally fix this, found in the link below
[how to setup custom web server in visual studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178108.aspx)