# ASP.NET v2 app on Server 2016: 404.3 error

Tags: asp.net

I just copied an asp.net v2 app (.net v2) from a win2003 box to a new server2016 box.

When I hit the app url on the server2016 box, I get this error:

```
HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found

The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.
```

What is missing in my server2016 iis env to resolve this?
(Seems like the aspx handler should already be there! I think I installed all the relevant IIS pieces.)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388066/the-page-you-are-requesting-cannot-be-served-because-of-the-extension-configura?rq=1

Comment: @Amy No, sorry. This does not dupe that old thread. This is new ver of windows (server 2016), and it should not suffer from those old issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in this case was simply that asp.net was not installed on the system...

On Server 2016, this is an easy thing to miss.