# HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found in IIS 8.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have installed IIS 8.5 on Windows 8.1. And I have add my framework 4.0 application in IIS from PORT 81. Framework 4.0 is already with windows 8.1. So I have run localhost:81/Home.aspx it shows an error like as follows

**HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found**

**The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.**

How to solve this.

Comment: Did you already register your .NET Framework with IIS, did you add the applicable feature? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388066/the-page-you-are-requesting-cannot-be-served-because-of-the-extension-configura)

Comment: Now its open. but Images, css, js files not Loaded. Static content was checked in Common HTTP Features.

Comment: What do you get? Which links are you calling?