# Code for download .dat file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have try to code for user to download the .dat file by using Response.Redirect.
However, it always show me this error.

```
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension 
configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be
downloaded, add a MIME map.
```

My sample code for Response.redirect

```
Response.Redirect(filepath, false);
```

I don't no what wrong with it. Plus,I can download .xlsx file by using this code.

Thanks for helping me.

This is the updated code that have no response to download.
**EDITED CODE**

```
string fpath = Server.MapPath("data") + "\\" + filename + ".dat";
 if (File.Exists(fpath))
{
File.Delete(fpath);
}
StreamWriter swExtLogFile = new StreamWriter(fpath, true);
try
{
int i;
foreach (DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
{
object[] array = row.ItemArray;
for (i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
{
swExtLogFile.Write(array[i].ToString());
}
swExtLogFile.WriteLine(array[i].ToString());
}
swExtLogFile.Close();
swExtLogFile.Dispose();
FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(fpath);
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fInfo.Length.ToString());
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", 
string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", fInfo.Name));
 Response.Flush();
Response.TransmitFile(fInfo.FullName);
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Comment: Have u checked on IIS to add the MIME type in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration." error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388066/the-page-you-are-requesting-cannot-be-served-because-of-the-extension-configura)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

You don't have to do MIME map.

```
private void dwnldFile(string filepath)
{
    FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(filepath);
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fInfo.Length.ToString);
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", fInfo.Name));
    Response.Flush();
    Response.TransmitFile(fInfo.FullName)
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply me.
But this error have thrown after adding the code
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.

This error have shown before also, but I not actually know what have cause it.

Comment: You have to show your code for better understanding.

Comment: The System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
is coming from Response.End()

Comment: Are you using thread? if so can you do this after the execution of thread?

Comment: Replace Response.End() with  HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

Comment: Ok, now don't have any error shown, but I don't seen my file have been download.

Comment: I have edited the code. I found out that Response.Transmit code did not pop out any download dialog even the code is go through it.