# Setting .NET Website on IIS Server in Windows Server 2016 Environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-server-2016

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzWdP.png)I am setting up my web application (working) in the Windows Server 2016 Environment which has the IIS role set up. My application outputs the following error when I try to run it: "The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration" error.

I have a simple application that has a label and needs to change the text of label on Page Load. My .aspx files work if I don't mention the CodeBehind file .aspx.cs file .

I believe this is a case of .aspx.cs file access. I have a much bigger application and I made this small one for asking this question. My guess is that I cannot access my .aspx.cs file.

I have tried adding "allow fileExtensions=".cs" ....." and this add cs to the list of allowed files. I have also tried using the aspnet_regiis -i to install asp.net which worked correctly.

As for my setup, I have added the IIS role, installed the ASP.NET 4.5 and its Extensible feature and also ASP.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Intro.aspx.cs" Inherits="Intro" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head runat="server">
   </head>
<body>
    <asp:Label . ...../>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE :Thank you all for your responses. This stackoverflow community is great . As for the solution I enabled .NET 3.5 features , .net 4.5 features, and all features related to a Web Server . A more concrete answer would help but this worked for me. Thank you all .

[Web.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7G16f.png)

Comment: You could possibly enable the fault tracing in IIS and see the full error. It is also possible that web features over Server Manager is not installed.

Comment: @Hozikimaru , What other steps do I have to take other than the ones listed on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-asp-net-modules
If I missed something, I can fix it now. I thought that's all I need to do. Researched online and found some fixes(mentioned in my post) that did not work for me.

Comment: DO NOT `"allow fileExtensions=".cs"`! Does your site run locally when you debug from Visual Studio? if it does, this is a deployment issue, how did you deploy the site to IIS?

Comment: @ChrisSchaller There are just two files in the "Default Web Site" that is provided by default by the IIS Manager - 'Intro.aspx' and 'Intro.aspx.cs' . I don't think it can be a deployment issue. You can try reproducing the environment too . I think that I am missing something here. I just followed instructions on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-asp-net-modules to set up the IIS and then just created two pages inside in the Default Web Site

Comment: You should check other threads on 404.3, but exposing .cs is not the solution.

Comment: @survivor Have you tried publishing your web application and then place the published files on the server?

Comment: Did you try the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388066/the-page-you-are-requesting-cannot-be-served-because-of-the-extension-configura

Comment: @ZhaoHainan I did see that . Thank you for your response.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I am using a Windows 2016 Environment with the IIS Server . If it doesn't work on my local I don't think it will work anywhere else .