# How to allow access to website created in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-access

So, I decided to set up my own websites in a Windows Server 2019 environment. I think I got everything right so far, my test website is available on the browser.

However, it is only available when I set the default page as index.html. It is an ASP website, so

1. when I delete the index.htm file from the folder so that it should pick/point to default.aspx, I get the error 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
2. with the default as index.html, any links from this index file to other folders like pages/default.aspx are also denied with the error 404 - File or directory not found. But when I create an index.html I am only able to access it by typing the full file name, as in mydomain.com/pages/index.html, and not as mydomain.com/pages

What am I missing in order to complete this setup?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you launch IIS and check the default documents?

eg this:
[image]

And then this:

[image]

Note that you can click on any of the default pages, and the move them up, or down as to which start up page is to be the default.

[image]

so, in above, we would want to move default.aspx to the top.

Comment: Thank you so much! That helped a lot. The I realised quite a number of features that needed to be added, especially installation of .net framework 3.5! got additional help from Kevin Brydon comments here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388066/the-page-you-are-requesting-cannot-be-served-because-of-the-extension-configura